# Can't use multiple VLOOKUPs in one formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I am trying to lookup a value from each of my excel sheets, and then add them. It's for a school assignment, so I'm only allowed to use the following formulas:
VLOOKUP; HLOOKUP; IF; SUM;SUMIF; AVERAGE; AND; OR.

I have 3 sheets, called Fredericton, Saint John & Moncton, all of which have the same structure.

I've tried adding the lookup values this way:

```
=VLOOKUP(A4, Fredericton!A4:B15, 2, FALSE) + VLOOKUP(A4, 'Saint John'!A4:B15, 2, FALSE) + VLOOKUP(A4, Moncton!A4:B15, 2, FALSE)
```

But this seems not to work, as the return is something that ressembles a date (10/12/2180). But when I test each VLOOKUP formula alone, it works as intended (The three lookups return seperately the following values respectively: 32950, 31533, 38072).

Upon further inspection, when I summed the return of this cell (the date-like value) with something else, it returned a correct value. So the problem is that it's not displaying the value correctly in the cell (which should be 102,555).

Comment: All three return a number?  If even one returns an error, it will fail.

Comment: @ScottCraner It's spelled correctly in the worksheet

Comment: how exactly it doesn't work? Have you tried [evaluating](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7) it?

Comment: @MátéJuhász I sadly can't evaluate, because I'm using webExcel

Comment: So the problem is that you have the cell in which the formula is place formatted as a Date when it should be `General`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use SUMIF:

```
=SUMIF(Fredericton!A:A,A4,Fredericton!B:B)+SUMIF('Saint John'!A:A,A4,'Saint John'!B:B)+SUMIF(Moncton!A:A,A4,Moncton!B:B)
```

If the value is not found on one of the sheets, VLOOKUP will return an error and then the whole formula will error.  With SUMIF if the value is not found it will return `0`.

And make sure the Cell is formatted 'General'

Comment: Formatting the cell as "General" solved the problem. Thanks alot!